# Jasper report not working in other computer/system

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have developed an application using Java on Netbeans 8.2 IDE, in which I have used jasper report. My main jasper report has two sub reports to it.

I converted the .jar file into .exe file (added all the library files)using the Jar2Exe application.

**Issue:** When I run the .exe file on another system only the reports are not working..the error message display is as below..

**Error msg:** "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.jrexception:resource not found at : C:\project1\secure\report1 subreport.jasper"

Comment: Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Also, try to be more consise on telling us what your specific situation is. For example list what you mean by "another system"

Comment: I meant other PC

Comment: You should mention the version of java that you are using to build and compile the code on the "other pc"

Comment: How do you load the Jasper report template (_.jasper_ file) in you Java code? It looks like you are using hardcoded path `C:\project1\secure\report1 subreport.jasper` instead of class path or stream from class loader resource.

Comment: (in the main report  report1.jrxml)                                                  
<subreport isUsingCache="false" runToBottom="false">
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="275" height="125" uuid="7c33d4b6-f433-4af8-bb36-5aed70100ccd"/>

<subreportParameter name="col">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{col}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
    
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["report1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>

Comment: In the java code:                                                                              
Connection conn=MySqlConnect.ConnectDB();
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("col",col);
InputStreamJasperIS=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Secure/report1.jasper");
JasperPrint JasPrn = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperIS, map, conn);
JasperViewer.viewReport(JasPrn,false);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasPrn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In master report change `<subreportExpression><![CDATA["report1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>` on:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["secure/report1_subreport1.jasper"]]</subreportExpression>
```

It means that the main report will reference subreport using full package path. And make sure that you don't have `SUBREPORT_DIR` parameter set.

---

If it still does not work then you can pass subreport to main report from Java using input stream:

```
InputStream subReport1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/secure/report1_subreport1.jasper");
parameters.put("SUBREPORT1", subReport1);
```

In main Jasper report you will use this expressin:

```
<subreportExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1}]]></subreportExpression>
```

And don't forget to declare the `SUBREPORT1` parameter for the main report:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT1" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Comment: @Cgrim....thanks a lot....the second option worked for me... :) Thank you for the time and effort you took to explain me in detail.... really appreciate...